# how do you find the square root of a number in applescript

Tags: applescript, calculator, square-root

I have a simple calculator code and I want to include square root in it. I am relatively new to applescript and I have no idea how. It might be nooby but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the exponent to `0.5`.

For example:

```
set num_ to 25.1
set sqrt_ to num_ ^ 0.5
```